# Redirecting http traffic to https in Apache without using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mod-alias

I am trying a pretty simple thing that I would normally do using a RewriteRule (and which works perfectly when I do).

**My goal:**
Force certain (not all) URLs to use the `https` protocol.

**Caveats:**

- Apache is behind a crypto-offloader. We would like a single virtual host that deals with both the unencrypted and the decrypted traffic. The offloader forwards all traffic to the same port and sets the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. (It also sets the new `Forwarded` header for future compatibility, but I will leave that out below for brevity.)
- Everything I have read lately suggests to use `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` instead of `RewriteRule`. Accordingly, I would like to avoid `RewriteRule` if possible.
- The URLs I wish to force are reverse proxies that I have configured in a `<LocationMatch>` section within my virtual host.
- The virtual host has multiple `Alias` entries that all correspond to valid names that are included in the TLS certificate (i.e. I don't want/need to force users to use the canonical name)
- It seems that `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` are unable to make use of the `%{HTTP_HOST}` server variable. This means I would need extra logic to have a different `RedirectMatch` line depending on the host that was use by the client (Messy).
- In the event that I NEED to use `mod_rewrite` for this, it would be good to have the `RewriteRule` inside the `<LocationMatch>` section to keep the configuration for that path/proxy in one place. However this also seems to cause problems.

Time for some example code to help explain this. All of the following examples reside within a `VirtualHost` section as follows:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAlias anothervalidalias.com
```

**Option 1** - Using `RedirectMatch`. This works but forces the hostname.

```
<LocationMatch "/backendcontextroot">
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass "http://192.168.0.2:8080/backendcontextroot"
    <If "-z req('X-Forwarded-Proto')">
        RedirectMatch ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1
    </If>
</LocationMatch>
```

**Option 2** - Using `RedirectMatch`. This would be my **ideal** solution, but the HTTP_HOST does not work. Apache sends no response back to the client.

```
<LocationMatch "/backendcontextroot">
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass "http://192.168.0.2:8080/backendcontextroot"
    <If "-z req('X-Forwarded-Proto')">
        RedirectMatch ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
    </If>
</LocationMatch>
```

**Option 3** - Using `RewriteRule` within a `LocationMatch` block. If I really cannot use `Redirect` and am forced to use `RewriteRule` then this would be my preferred method as it keeps the configuration for the `/backendcontextroot` reverse proxy together in one place. However, this produces some 'funky' redirects...

```
<LocationMatch "/backendcontextroot">
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass "http://192.168.0.2:8080/backendcontextroot"
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
</LocationMatch>
```

This redirects to:
    https://www.example.com/proxy:http://192.168.0.2:8080/backendcontextroot

**Option 4** - Using `RewriteRule` *outside* the `LocationMatch` block. This works, but the configuration for this reverse proxy is then 'spread around'. It also uses `RewriteRule` despite suggestions that I should avoid it if possible.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backendcontextroot
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1

<LocationMatch "/backendcontextroot">
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass "http://192.168.0.2:8080/backendcontextroot"
</LocationMatch>
```

Am I stuck using option 4 or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectMatch` is only good for relatively indiscriminate redirects, which is why it meets the needs of most. Keep your crypto proxy clean and either add a header to the back-end request denoting the connection was encrypted (not sure how to do that), or connect to a different port, e.g. `8443` that you would add to the same `Listen` or `<VirtualHost>` that has the `8080` in the back-end. The back-end would still not use an encrypted connection but would know whether the the connection is "secure" by checking headers or port. These checks can be performed by the back-end – quite easily – in either `RewriteCond`s via `%{HTTP:X-Your-Https-Header}` or `%{SERVER_PORT}`, or in the site's scripting language and have redirects sent from it, since only it knows which URLs require redirects. It can send out the redirect complete with `https:` since that's what the client needs to request, and your back-end will get the new request proxied with the correct header/port.

**Edit:** example of configuration on crypto server

```
<LocationMatch "/backendcontextroot">
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    <If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
        ProxyPass "http://192.168.0.2:8443/backendcontextroot"
    <Else>
        ProxyPass "http://192.168.0.2:8080/backendcontextroot"
    </If>
</LocationMatch>
```