# Using RedirectMatch with HTTP_HOST in the destination

Tags: apache, http-redirect, mod-alias

I keep reading that, where possible, I should not be using `mod_rewrite`. As such, I am trying to do a http to https rewrite with RedirectMatch.

**Question:** How can I use `RedirectMatch` and use Apache server variables (such as `%{HTTP_HOST}`) in the URL parameter?

This code fails to return a response to the client (Chrome):

```
RedirectMatch ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

I recently asked a similar question to this, but it may have been too wordy and lacks direction for an answer: [Redirecting http traffic to https in Apache without using mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263713/redirecting-http-traffic-to-https-in-apache-without-using-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, You can't use variables of that type with Redirect/RedirectMatch. If you need variables, such as `%{HTTP_HOST}`, use mod_rewrite.

Note: I commend you for not trying to use mod_rewrite right away, because most people will go for mod_rewrite even for the simplest of redirections, which is clearly overkill and most times it is just looking to complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks! This problem has been unproductively burning a hole in my head for a day now. On new implementations, I like to try and do things 'the right way' even if it's harder. In this case, `mod_rewrite` it is!

Answer (score 16):

If you're using 2.4.19 or later, the [`Redirect` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) has a somewhat obscure feature: putting it inside a `Location` or `LocationMatch` will enable [expression syntax](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html).

So your example can be written as

```
<LocationMatch ^(?<PATH>.*)>
    Redirect "https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{env:MATCH_PATH}"
</LocationMatch>
```

(Here, the `?<PATH>` notation means that the match capture will be saved to an environment variable with the name `MATCH_PATH`. That's how we can use it later in the `Redirect`.)

It's even easier if you always redirect using the entire request path, because you can replace the capture group entirely with the `REQUEST_URI` variable:

```
<Location "/">
    Redirect "https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}"
</Location>
```

Now, is this easier to maintain/understand than just using mod_rewrite for this one case? Maybe not. But it's an option.

Comment: The Apache config syntax isn't actually XML, so <Location /> just means that the argument to Location is "/". Surrounding it in quotes is probably more readable in this case.

Comment: I'm already doing all this inside a `LocationMatch` so that would have been gorgeous. Alas, we are stuck, for now, on 2.4.6 as we are using RHEL7. All the good stuff came later lol. I may consider the RedHat Software Collections version (2.4.18) if there are enough compelling reasons to leave the version included in core RHEL7.

Comment: FWIW Jacob had taught me about this example earlier, but imho I thought it was too convoluted to be considered a good answer.

Comment: if you add the www in `Redirect "https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}"` if you browse http://www.yoursite.com it will redirect to https://www.www.yoursite.com

Comment: `<Location "/">` can create an infinite redirect loop. To redirect your web root, use `<Location ~ "^/$">` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Writing for users who might face the same in future.

Not sure how you are adding vhost entries.

I guess this vhost entries are added automatically with help of some programming script.
Do you use VhostDirective with ServerName?

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName example.domain.com
</VirutalHost>
```

If so, then you can use the same domain value for populating RedirectMatch field.

If you are manually adding vhost entries just write that domain URL value explicitly instead of HTTP_HOST.

Or let me know if its a different scenario.